# Way to defer/load_only in SQLAlchemy 2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any any way to incorporate defer() or load_only() types of methods in SQL 2.0 types of queries, except adding deffered() to the columns in tables?

What i.m trying to get is smthg like:

```
class Signals(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'signals'

    id = sa.Column(sa.BigInteger(), primary_key=True)
    value_type_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey('value_types.id'))
    sources_id = sa.Column(sa.BigInteger(), sa.ForeignKey('sources.id'))
    acl = sa.Column(JSONB())


stmt = select(Signals).join(Signals.value_types).defer(acl)

session = Session(engine)

# get all fields except acl
result = await session.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded/modified your example a bit to have a full workable example.

In short, you can use `.options(defer('field_name'))` to prevent loading specific fields. However, implicitly loading those fields later (as the name "defer" implies) will not work.

Documentation link: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#deferred

```
import asyncio

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, defer, sessionmaker

meta = sa.MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=meta)


class ValueType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'value_types'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class Signals(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'signals'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    value_type_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), sa.ForeignKey('value_types.id'))
    acl = sa.Column(sa.String())

    value_type = relationship(ValueType)


async def async_main():
    engine = create_async_engine(
        "sqlite+aiosqlite:///", echo=True,
    )

    async_session = sessionmaker(
        engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
    )

    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(meta.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(meta.create_all)

    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            v = ValueType()
            session.add_all([
                Signals(acl='acl1', value_type=v),
                Signals(acl='acl2', value_type=v),
            ])

        stmt = sa.select(Signals).join(Signals.value_type).options(defer('acl'))
        results = await session.execute(stmt)
        for r in results.scalars():
            print(r)
            # await session.refresh(r, ['acl'])  # <-- uncomment to make the following line work
            print(r.acl)  # <-- error here, deferred loads will not work as the cursor is not awaited

    await engine.dispose()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's any way to load the deferred column (or relationship) after the fact without having to query the whole parent object again with new options?

Comment: Sure, you just need to make sure you query it in a way that you can await. For example, prior to the `print(r.acl)` line, insert a `await session.refresh(r, ['acl'])` to query just the acl attribute for a single row. However, I'd caution that this is likely to cause performance issues if not done carefully.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks. However, it doesn't look like I can use things like `joinedload` in the `session.refresh`. In the end, it's likely more efficient to just query the root object again, as the relationship tree is somewhat deep and I'm carefully controlling how things are loaded.